Autofill SMS Passcode Not Working in Vue.js/Ionic App on iOS
I'm developing an application using Vue.js and Ionic, and I've encountered an issue with the SMS passcode autofill feature on iOS. In my app, users receive a one-time SMS passcode for authentication. Ideally, when this SMS is received, the iPhone should detect the passcode and offer to autofill it into the app's input fields. However, when I tap on the passcode, which appears above the iOS keyboard, it does not auto fill the input boxes.
Here's how I've implemented the input fields in my app:
<form>
  <input
    v-for="(n, index) in code"
    :key="index"
    type="text"
    pattern="\d*"
    :id="'input_' + index"
    maxlength="1"
    v-model="code[index]"
    @input="handleInput"
    @keydown="isNumber"
    @keydown.delete="handleDelete"
    @paste="onPaste"
  />
</form>

And here's a snippet from the script:
handleInput(event) {
      const inputType = event.inputType;
      let currentActiveElement = event.target;

      if (inputType === "insertText") {
        if (currentActiveElement && currentActiveElement.nextElementSibling) {
          currentActiveElement.nextElementSibling.focus();
        } else {
          currentActiveElement.blur();
        }
      }

      if (inputType === "insertFromPaste" && this.dataFromPaste) {
        for (const num of this.dataFromPaste) {
          const id = parseInt(currentActiveElement.id.split("_")[1]);
          currentActiveElement.value = num;
          this.code[id] = num;
          if (currentActiveElement && currentActiveElement.nextElementSibling) {
            currentActiveElement.nextElementSibling.focus();
            currentActiveElement = currentActiveElement.nextElementSibling;
          } else {
            currentActiveElement.blur();
            break;
          }
        }
      }
},
isNumber(event) {
      event.currentTarget.value = "";
      const keyPressed = event.key;
      if (!this.keysAllowed.includes(keyPressed)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
},
handleDelete(event) {
      let value = event.target.value;
      let currentActiveElement = event.target;
      if (!value) {
        const id = parseInt(currentActiveElement.id.split("_")[1]);
        this.code[id] = "";
        if (currentActiveElement && currentActiveElement.previousElementSibling) {
          currentActiveElement.previousElementSibling.focus();
        }
      }
},
onPaste(event) {
      if (event.clipboardData) {
        const pastedData = event.clipboardData.getData("text").trim().split("").slice(0, 6); // Ensure only first 6 characters are considered
        for (let i = 0; i < pastedData.length; i++) {
          const inputIndex = parseInt(event.target.id.split("_")[1]) + i;
          if (inputIndex < this.code.length) {
            this.code[inputIndex] = pastedData[i];
            const nextInput = document.getElementById(`input_${inputIndex + 1}`);
            if (nextInput) {
              nextInput.focus(); // Move focus to next input field
            }
          }
        }
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default paste behavior
      }
},

keysAllowed = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
I have tested the copy and paste function on web browser and on android devices. They are working as expected. However, in iOS devices, it is not working.
Please suggest and many thanks!
